# C++ dynamic memory allocation of a local variable

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, allocation

I had a computer science class at school and our teacher was talking about dynamic memory allocation and why

```
cin>>size;
int array[size]; // According to him this should result in a compiler error
```

this **shouldn't** work and instead we were supposed to use:

```
int *p, size;
cin>>size;
p = new int[size]
...
delete[] p;
```

My question is, why does the first example work if you cannot declare dynamically arrays like that?

**UPDATE:** All tests are made in *GNU GCC Compliler* and the code above is inside the *main* function

Comment: Add the flags `-pedantic -ansi` to make sure your compiler is not using extensions. You should probably also add `-Werror -Wall -Wextra`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using a non-standard compiler, that supports variable length arrays. Your professor is right, `int array[size]` shouldn't compile.

Your professor is also <del>wrong</del> telling you to use `p = new int[size]`. What he should do is tell you to use `std::vector<int> p(size)`. (okay, for educational purposes this is OK) :)

Comment: This. I swear the usage of [std::vector](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) cannot be taught enough these days.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore I updated my question. Does that change anything?

Comment: `g++ -pedantic -Wall file.cpp` is strongly encouraged!

Comment: @Itehnological No. Even if it compiles and runs, declaring a dynamically-sized array is not a good standard to follow. Using `new` is better, but for dynamic arrays, the std::vector class is what any decent C++ programmer would recommend.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `p = new int[size]`, it's just a simple dynamic array.
`std::vector` is more powerful data structure, but it's more advanced

Comment: @Itehnological no it doesn't. Compilers can have extensions, but the language forbids VLA's.

Comment: @FredericBlase the implementation of vector is more advanced, but that's why new programmers should use it; it takes care of advanced complexity for them instead of making the programmer do it manually with an array. Also raw arrays should be avoided because they're inconsistent and behave strangely (can't be assigned to, can't be passed to/returned from functions by value, can be implicitly converted to a pointer to their first sub-object, their declarators get treated as declarators for pointers in some contexts, etc.).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: One thing at a time. If this is the first lecture on dynamically sized arrays they need to work up to those concepts.

Comment: @bames53 they should use vector only if they know what it is and how it works. Same about raw arrays, but you can't understand vector without understanding raw arrays.

Comment: @FredericBlase Eventually one should learn about raw arrays and should be able to implement vector, but starting out, no, there's no need to understand the intricacies of vector's implementation. One only needs to understand its use. For example Bjarne Stroustrup's introductory programming book _Programming: Principals and Practice Using C++_ introduces vectors in chapter 4 but waits until the last half of chapter 18 to discuss raw arrays. This is exactly the right approach to arrays in C++.